# Url getting duplicated in django: sign/sign/

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

The sign/ url is getting duplicated on itself, as shown in the below image. How can I stop this url duplication? It was working fine before taking input from the user. When the user clicks on the submit button it duplicated itself in the url.

[image]

**This is View.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse 
# Create your views here.

def Home(response):
    return render(response, "main/index.html",{}) 

def sign_up_in(response):
    if response.method == 'POST':
        email = response.POST.get('eemail') 
        print(email)                         
    return render(response, "main/sign_up_in.html",{})
```

**This is urls.py**

```
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
   path("", views.Home, name = "Homes"), 
   path("sign/", views.sign_up_in, name = "sign_up_in") 
]
```

**This is urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include("main.urls")),
    path('sign/', include("main.urls")),
]
```

**This is my sign_up_in.html code**

```
                <form method="POST" class="form" id="a-form" action="{% url 'sign_up_in' %}">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <h2 class="form_title title">Create Account</h2>
                    <div class="form__icons"><img class="form__icon" src="svg_data" alt=""><img class="form__icon" src="svg_data"><img class="form__icon" src="svg_data"></div><span class="form__span">or use email for registration</span>
                    <input class="form__input" type="text" placeholder="Name" name="eemail">
                    <input class="form__input" type="text" placeholder="Email">
                    <input class="form__input" type="password" placeholder="Password">
                    <button class="button" type="submit">SIGN UP</button>
                </form>
           
                <form method="POST" class="form" id="b-form" action="">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <h2 class="form_title title">Sign in to Website</h2>
                    <div class="form__icons"><img class="form__icon" src="svg_data" alt=""><img class="form__icon" src="svg_data"><img class="form__icon" src="svg_data"form__span">or use your email account</span>
                    <input class="form__input" type="text" placeholder="Email" name="eemail">
                    <input class="form__input" type="password" placeholder="Password"><a class="form__link">Forgot your password?</a>
                    <button class="button">SIGN IN</button>
                </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The duplicate `sign/` appeared because you define two URLs that maps the `sign_up_in` view.

The first one is on the project level `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('sign/', include("main.urls")),
]
```

This pattern will also **"include"** the urls from your app `urls.py`.

```
urlpatterns = [
   ...
   path("sign/", views.sign_up_in, name = "sign_up_in") 
]
```

So, whenever you call the `sign_up_in` URL in the template the URL will show the full path based on how you defined your URL pattern. In your case it is

```
sign/ <-- from your project urls.py
     sign/ <--- from your app urls.py

# output:
sign/sign/
```

In order for this to work properly, you need to remove the `path('sign/', include("main.urls"))`.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('/', include("main.urls")),
]
```

So whenever you have to define a new URL in your `main` app `urls.py`, *do not repeat it* in your project-level URLs to avoid unwanted results.

> **NOTE:** Your `main.urls` will always start on leading `/` so it is wise to
> omit any leading `/` in your `main` app `urls.py` whenever you define new
> URLs.

Comment: The explanation was so good. Thanks, now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

In your app urls.py change

```
path("sign/", views.sign_up_in, name = "sign_up_in")
```

to

```
path("", views.sign_up_in, name = "sign_up_in")
```

You alreday defined "sign/" in your main urls.py so every url from this app will start with sign/*

Comment: I have 2 pages, first is home page and second one is sign up page. When the user clicks on sign up button it should go to sign/ url.

Comment: I tried your above solution, but it doesn't shows the sign up page.

Answer (score 0):

```
    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('', include("main.urls")),
        path('sign/', include("main.urls")), #remove this 
    ]
```

You already included `main.urls` once

Comment: The empty one is for my home page and the sign/ is for sign up page. When the user clicks on the sign up button, it should go on sign/ url.

Comment: @KshitijKarkera This is actually correct, the `path('', include("main.urls"))` will suffice it because main.urls has provided the `sign/` for the `sign_up_in` view. Check out my answer for more details.
 `